# How to build a custom scheduler for Spark

Tags: apache-spark, scheduling

For a personal project, I am looking into implementing some scheduling algorithms into Spark and measure their performances in terms of time and other metrics. I have found that Spark implements two algorithms which are FIFO and a Fair scheduler and that it uses a backend such as : Apache MESOS or YARN to schedule the different jobs on each executor.

I don't know however if it's possible to create your own scheduler with its own logic (derived from fair scheduling), would there be a class that you can extend and define your own scheduling algorithm ? Any links or resources regarding this matter would be helpful.

Comment: Do you want to write a scheduler (like yarn/mesos) or a scheduling algorithm (Fair schedule. FIFO etc)?

Comment: @AvishekBhattacharya I want to write a scheduling algorithm